# Recursive solution of ordered Coin Combinations II (CSES)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

[Question Link](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1636/)

> Consider a money system consisting of n coins. Each coin has a positive integer value. Your task is to calculate the number of distinct ordered ways you can produce a money sum x using the available coins.
>
> For example, if the coins are {2,3,5} and the desired sum is 9, there are 3 ways:
>
> ```
> 2+2+5
> 3+3+3
> 2+2+2+3
> ```

I am trying to write recursive solution for this.
I came up with [this](https://cses.fi/paste/e690e97bf8068ba92cf0cf/) code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
#define M 1000000007
 
vector<int>arr;
vector<vector<int>>dp;

int solve(int i,int target){
    if(i>=(int)arr.size()) return 0;
    if(target<0) return 0;
    if(target==0) return 1;
    if(dp[i][target]!=-1) return dp[i][target];
    return dp[i][target]=(solve(i,target-arr[i])%M+solve(i+1,target)%M)%M;
}

int main(){
    int n,target;
    cin>>n>>target;
    arr.resize(n);
    dp.resize(n+1,vector<int>(target+1,-1));
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cout<<solve(0,target);
}
```

but this code is giving time-limit-exceeded. How can this code be written in a recursive manner so that it gets accepted? Here is [non-recursive approach](https://usaco.guide/problems/cses-1636-coin-combinations-ii-ordered/solution) but I want to know how to write a recursive version of this.

Comment: Linked solution uses a one dimension `dp`, whereas you use a 2D vector...

Comment: [Converting Iterative Code to Recursive Code](https://www.educative.io/collection/page/6151088528949248/4547996664463360/6292303276670976) might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

an example of recursive sum which select results would be:

```
void recursive_sum( IN const std::vector<int>& coins, 
                    IN int result,
                    OUT std::vector<std::string>& res,
                    IN std::deque<int> numbers = {},
                    IN int actual_sum = 0)
{
    for(auto& n: coins)
    {
        int nsum = actual_sum + n; 
        if(nsum == result)
            insert_result(res, copy_insert(numbers, n));
        else if(nsum < result)
            recursive_sum(coins, result, res, copy_insert(numbers, n), nsum);
    }
}
```

a main similar to this would do the job:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> res{};
    std::vector<int> coins{};
    int sum_result = 0;
    
    input_coins(coins);
    input_sum_result(sum_result);
    recursive_sum(coins, sum_result, res);
    out_result(res);
    return 0;
}
```

if you want to take a look to a full version of this example click [here](https://pastebin.com/iFiwz3TU).

output example:

```
"
Insert a number or 'next' to continue
10
Actually coins are: { 10, }
Insert a number or 'next' to continue 
15
Actually coins are: { 10, 15, }
Insert a number or 'next' to continue 
25
Actually coins are: { 10, 15, 25, }
Insert a number or 'next' to continue 
next
Insert the sum result:
100
Possible sums are: 
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, }
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, }
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 10, }
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 25, }
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25, 15, }
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25, 10, 15, }
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25, 25, }
{10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, }
{10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 10, 15, 15, }
{10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 25, }
{10, 10, 10, 15, 25, 15, 15, }
{10, 10, 15, 15, 10, 25, 15, }
{10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 15, }
{10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 10, 25, }
{10, 10, 15, 15, 25, 25, }
{10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, }
{10, 15, 15, 25, 10, 25, }
{10, 15, 25, 25, 10, 15, }
{10, 15, 25, 25, 25, }
{10, 25, 10, 10, 10, 10, 25, }
{10, 25, 10, 10, 15, 10, 10, 10, }
{15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 25, }
{15, 25, 15, 15, 15, 15, }
{25, 25, 25, 10, 15, }
{25, 25, 25, 15, 10, }
{25, 25, 25, 25, }
"
```